# Blackberry sqlite - Cannot prepare already prepared statement exception

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

In blackberry sqlite while executing the below code i getting exception "Cannot prepare already prepared statement"

```
public Department[] getDepartment()
{
    Department[]  department = null;

    try
    {         
        database = DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);         
        Statement st = database.createStatement("SELECT code, name, status FROM Department");          

        st.prepare();

        Cursor c = st.getCursor();           
        Row r;
        int i = 0;
        department = new Department[i];
        while(c.next()) 
        {
            r = c.getRow();
            i++;
            Department dept = (Department) r.getObject(i);
            department[i] = dept;               
        }

        st.close();
        database.close();
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) 
    {         
        System.out.println("Exception occured --------------" +e.getMessage());
    }    
    return department;
}
```

anybody know solution for this

Comment: Which exact line is throwing the exception? The actual prepare call?

Comment: when i call the st.prepare();

Comment: What URI are you using for the database? Does it actually exist at that location?

Comment: Location exists, but still i am getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

The `st.prepare()` is only necessary if the statement is not prepared, which means:

- The statement references an external variable
- The statement references a computed variable

In this case, neither is the case, so the statement is redundant.

**References**

- [SQLite: File History - prepare.c](http://sqlite.org/src/finfo?name=src/prepare.c)
- [Getting “Re-preparing already prepared query” warning with caching enabled · Issue #581 · Netflix/astyanax · GitHub](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/issues/581)
- [SQLite: View Ticket - Repreparation errors are always returned as SQLITE_SCHEMA](http://sqlite.org/src/tktview/8d510499ccbac2f03efa)